# Rust: one mutable reference to a particular piece of data at a time?

Tags: rust

I am noob to Rust and wanted to solidify my understanding of mutable reference in Rust.

```
fn mutate_me(st: &mut String)-> usize {
    st.push_str(" mutated.");
    st.len()
}
```

When I try using any one of either **x** or mutable reference **r1** there is no compilation error.

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = String::from("random");
    let r1 = &mut x;
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

This also work without any compilation error.

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = String::from("random");
    let r1 = &mut x;
    println!("{}", mutate_me(r1));
}
```

But the one below fails as I tried using both of them.

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = String::from("random");
    let r1 = &mut x;
    println!("{}", mutate_me(r1));
    println!("{}", x);
    println!("{}", *r1);
}
```

Does this imply that for mutable reference, whichever tried using it next first becomes valid and the other one invalid?

Comment: A mutable reference is an *exclusive* reference. You can't have two exclusive references at the same time to some data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a complement to @ChayimFriedman [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70495026/1695172). Usually (not always) you have to work around the borrowing and flow of your program using **scopes**, so that things are used and dropped to liberate outer ones. For example your third case could be transformed as follows:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut x = String::from("random");
    let res = {
        let r1 = &mut x;
        println!("{}", r1);
        mutate_me(r1)
    };
    println!("{}", res);
    println!("{}", x);
    
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9f3a0d4d7404a0351adfe3f0d9deabc)

Comment: Since NLL this is usually unnecessary. Anyway, you can also insert a call to `drop()` to get the same effect.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, nice point, thanks!, you are right, drop should produce the same effect. I think it would depend on the developer, I usually think on scopes instead of using explicit drop calls.

Comment: Yup. This is a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

From the moment you borrow something to the last usage of the reference, the reference is considered alive for borrowing. Accessing an object while a mutable reference to it is alive is an error.

In your first example, you don't use `r1` (it is immediately dropped), so the region of code where you can use `x` is between the two statements `let r1 = &mut x;` and `let r1 = &mut x;`, meaning... zero code.

In the second example you never use `x`, so in the code region `x` is invalid to use - between the declaration of `r1` and its use - `x` is never actually used. Everything is fine.

The problem is in the third example, when you use `x` in the "invalid range". You can remove the `println!("{}", mutate_me(r1));` - it doesn't matter.

The compiler points on these three important points: where the reference was created, when it's being used later, and where you perform the invalid access (this is called the "three-points models" in the [NLL RFC](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2094-nll.html#leveraging-intuition-framing-errors-in-terms-of-points)):

```rust
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `x` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:4:20
  |
3 |     let r1 = &mut x;
  |              ------ mutable borrow occurs here
4 |     println!("{}", x);
  |                    ^ immutable borrow occurs here
5 |     println!("{}", *r1);
  |                    --- mutable borrow later used here
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=464a6a941a5d9546a9da7d5edc06a8b7).